# CMake FetchContent does not copy libraries

Tags: c++, cmake

I am using CMake FetchContent to download and build a third party library(realsense2 in this case). After trying out the googletest example from the official documentation (https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.11/module/FetchContent.html) I was impressed how easy it works. Including headers was done magically. Now with realsense2 SDK I have a problem.

I need to do add an additional include_directories command like this:

```
FetchContent_Declare(
realsense2
GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense.git
GIT_TAG        v2.23.0
)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(realsense2)
FetchContent_GetProperties(realsense2)
if(NOT realsense2_POPULATED)
    FetchContent_Populate(realsense2)
    add_subdirectory(${realsense2_SOURCE_DIR} ${realsense2_BINARY_DIR})
endif()
//I should not be required to do this according to documentation
include_directories(${realsense2_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
```

If I do not do this, some headers are not found. Any suggestions regarding this problem?

EDIT: To clarify, this is how I added the libraries:

```
target_link_libraries(TestExe gtest gtest_main)
```

and the other exactly the same but this time it is not an exe its a dll

```
add_library(TestLib SHARED ${TestLib_HEADERS} ${TestLib_SOURCES} )
target_link_libraries(TestLib realsense2)
```

At this point I am more concerned about why I do not have to add any includes for googletest framework

Comment: "Including headers was done magically." - FetchContent itself does nothing in respect to include directories. So I don't understand what to you mean by the comment in your code `//I should not be required to do this according to documentation`. "If I do not do this, some headers are not found." - Please, show more details about this error.

Comment: For googletest, the only thing I did was a target_link_libraries(TestExe gtest gtest_main).  Without adding any additional command for includes. And regarding the headers not found for realsense2, it is just as I wrote...It is a normal "header not found" error which is solved by the "include_directories" command.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main purpose of `FetchContent` is a garantee that at the time of call

```
add_subdirectory(${Foo_SOURCE_DIR} ${Foo_BINARY_DIR})
```

the "fetched" project will be (as sources) in the `${Foo_SOURCE_DIR}` directory.

**How to use** the project inluded via `add_subdirectory` is completely **up to that project**:

1. Some projects (including gtest) create the library target `Foo` in a "modern" CMake way, by associating properties with it using `target_include_directories` and other commands. So, to use a library like this, it is sufficient to call `target_link_libraries`.
2. Some other projects require both `include_directories` and `target_link_libraries` to work with them.
3. Finally, there are many projects, which simply don't work when included via `add_subdirectory`. So `FetchContent` makes little sense for them.

Only a small subset of projects describe how to work with them via `add_subdirectory` approach. And `gtest` is among them.

But most projects simply don't describe this; if you want to use `add_subdirectory` with such a project, then you need to investigate the internals of that project to understand its usage (or use trial and error).

Comment: Thanks for your answer that surely helps. Maybe you can help me here as well: Adding two libraries with FetchContent that have both a add_custom_target(uninstall ...) will fail because of the duplicate command. Is there any way to solve this? Maybe use ExternalProject_Add() instead of FetchCommand?

Comment: Yes, `ExternalProject_Add`, which configures and builds external project without populating variables and targets in the main project is more "universal" way than simple `FetchContent`. Downside of the `ExternalProject` approach is that you need to know **exact paths** for refer to the project's libraries.

Comment: Note, that most CMake projects are designed to be installed and then used via `find_package`. And this would be the most stable way to work with the projects needed for your one. If you want to install other projects during the configuration of your one (so `find_package` will work), then it can be achieved with combining `execute_process` and `ExternalProject_Add` (just google for that approach).

Comment: Thanks for your insights. I managed to download and link OpenCV wtih ExternalProject_Add(). Now the final step I need is to copy the .dlls from install folder to executable folder. I wonder if there is an easy way or if I need to use custom commands

Comment: " I wonder if there is an easy way or if I need to use custom commands" - Just google for "cmake copy dll to executable".